# Could not install gems on docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rubygems, bundler, docker-compose

I'm developing a Rails app using Docker. Now I need to install a new gem, but that does not work.

If I run `docker-compose -f dcom-dev.yml run --user $(id -u)  web bundle exec gem install youtube_it` it gives me such an output:

```
Fetching: excon-0.51.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT)
    No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /.gem/ruby/2.3.0/cache/excon-0.51.0.gem
```

If I add `gem 'youtube_it'` to my `Gemfile` and then run `docker-compose -f dcom-dev.yml run --user $(id -u)  web bundle exec bundle install` it outputs like this:

```
Could not find gem 'youtube_it' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

What could be a problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are use wrong command for bundler.

```
docker-compose -f dcom-dev.yml run --user $(id -u)  web gem install youtube_it
```

or:

```
docker-compose -f dcom-dev.yml run --user $(id -u)  web bundle install
```

<sub>[Understanding Bundler](http://bundler.io/rationale.html)</sub>

Comment: Oh, God!
That's it! I use an alias for this long parameters. And once saw this mistake and corrected it on other machine and forget about it after that.
Thanks!

P.S. Зеленый, не грустите! :)